# Printing Arabic text in command prompt in Java

Tags: java, encoding, intellij-idea, arabic

I have a Java program which prints Arabic text to Command prompt in windows. I read the text in three ways,

- From Database
- From file
- From hard coded Arabic String

When I run the code from within the IDE (Intellij Idea) it works well i.e. prints the Arabic but it is not working when I run the program from Command prompt. I also print the character encoding, From IDE, the encoding is UTF-8 and from command prompt it is Cp1252. This is the problem. I also compiled and run the program using this command respectively,

```
javac -encoding UTF8 Testing.java
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 Testing
```

but this also didn't work. I also set an environment variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` to `-Dfile.encoding="UTF8"` but still not working. Arabic is shown as ?????... Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you defined any specific font to be used in your application?

Comment: This isn't something you can fix on the Java side, it's the command prompt that would need to be configured with an appropriate encoding and a font that can display Arabic characters.  Configuring Java to send UTF-8 won't help if the console isn't set up to expect it.